# Given $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3$ prove that $x/\sqrt{x^2+y+z} + y/\sqrt{y^2+x+z} + z/\sqrt{z^2+x+z} \le \sqrt3$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Given $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3$

Then prove that $${x\over\sqrt{x^2+y+z}} + {y\over\sqrt{y^2+x+z}} + {z\over\sqrt{z^2+x+y}} \le \sqrt 3$$

I tried using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but the inequality is coming in opposite direction.

Comment: I changed the numerators. Please check!

Comment: thnx..they were right..

Comment: This is only true if $x,y,z\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$(1+1+1)(x^2+y^2+z^2)\ge (x+y+z)^2\Longrightarrow x^2+y^2+z^2\ge x+y+z$$
and using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$(x^2+y+z)(1+y+z)\ge (x+y+z)^2\Longrightarrow \dfrac{\sqrt{1+y+z}}{x+y+z}\ge\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y+z}}$$
so
$$\Longleftrightarrow\dfrac{x\sqrt{1+y+z}+y\sqrt{1+z+x}+z\sqrt{1+x+y}}{x+y+z}\le\sqrt{3}$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}&(x\sqrt{1+y+z}+y\sqrt{1+z+x}+z\sqrt{1+z+x})^2\le[x+y+z][(x+y+z)+2(xy+yz+xz)]\\
&\le(x+y+z)[x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+xz)]=(x+y+z)^3
\end{align*}
so
$$\dfrac{x\sqrt{1+y+z}+y\sqrt{1+z+x}+z\sqrt{1+x+y}}{x+y+z}\le\sqrt{x+y+z}$$
and
$$\sqrt{x+y+z}\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $(a+b+c)^2 \leq 3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$.  Then multiply out the denominators and solve.

Alternatively, maximize the left hand side subject to the constraint.

Comment: I know this is an old problem, but how did you get the result at the end of the first line? I presume you require $\frac{x+y+z}{3}\geq 1$, which is not always true (take $x=\sqrt{3},\ y=z=0$).